# Detect div and resize other div if not present

Tags: jquery, find, width, parent, each

I have a list item with 3 columns, an image, text, and a table. They are all float left. I need to detect if the list item contains a div with the class '.Image', if this div is not present I need to resize the width of the div that has the class '.Text'.

I've attached the code and a JSFIDDLE below, option 2 is the one that needs to detect that there isn't a 'div.Image' instance and resize 'div.Text' to 450px.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/KEEEH/1/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Image').each().parent().find('div.Text').width(450);
});
```

CSS:

```
#listingItem{width:660px; background-color:#666666;}
.Image{width:100px;float:left; background-color:#cccccc; height:200px; padding:10px;}
.Text{width:350px;float:left;background-color:#666666; color:#FFFFFF; height:200px;padding:10px;}
.Table{width:150px; float:left;background-color:#999999; height:200px;padding:10px;}
.clr{clear:both;}
table tr td{color:#FFFFFF;}
```

HTML:

```
<h2>OPTION 1</h2>
<div id="listingItem">
    <div class="Image"><img src="http://foto.hrsstatic.com/fotos/0/3/256/256/80/FFFFFF/http%3A%2F%2Ffoto-origin.hrsstatic.com%2Ffoto%2F1%2F6%2F4%2F9%2Fteaser_164977.jpg/NJznvEm71tK4eSpZVLEFZA%3D%3D/128,128/6/Holiday_Inn_MIAMI_BEACH-OCEANFRONT-Miami_Beach-Exterior_view-5-164977.jpg" width="100" /></div>
    <div class="Text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras fringilla sagittis iaculis. Etiam tincidunt egestas urna, et congue lorem elementum eget. Morbi sed nibh rutrum, pulvinar metus a, bibendum purus. In porttitor ornare massa et dapibus. Duis tempor facilisis ipsum, sed tempus mauris ornare id. Donec in consequat est. Nunc pulvinar nibh in lorem suscipit, at eleifend tellus dictum. Proin congue leo eu dui feugiat condimentum. Sed sagittis sagittis consectetur. Quisque ut ultrices erat.
    </div>
    <div class="Table">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="150">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#b22222">
                    CONTENT
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>

<h2>OPTION 2</h2>

<div id="listingItem">
    <div class="Text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras fringilla sagittis iaculis. Etiam tincidunt egestas urna, et congue lorem elementum eget. Morbi sed nibh rutrum, pulvinar metus a, bibendum purus. In porttitor ornare massa et dapibus. Duis tempor facilisis ipsum, sed tempus mauris ornare id. Donec in consequat est. Nunc pulvinar nibh in lorem suscipit, at eleifend tellus dictum. Proin congue leo eu dui feugiat condimentum. Sed sagittis sagittis consectetur. Quisque ut ultrices erat.
    </div>
    <div class="Table">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="150">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#b22222">
                    CONTENT
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to change your ID for a class, since you can't repeat IDs then use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".listingItem" ).each(function() {
        if (!$(this).find('.Image').length){
            $(this).find('div.Text').width(450);
        }

    });    

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jy4Xr/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think this is more suitable for the type of things I'll be using this for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with just css.

```
.Text{width:450px;float:left;background-color:#666666; color:#FFFFFF; height:200px;padding:10px;}
.Image + .Text { width:350px; }
```

Set the default .Text width to 450. If the .Text element is preceded by an .Image element, adjust it to 350.

Comment: Note that this assumes your .Text element will always come AFTER the image. If that is not the case, this will not work.

Comment: Does this also work in ie 7 and 8? as most my site users will be using these browsers. Thanks

Comment: Supposedly buggy in IE7 (if the .Image element is dynamically inserted by javascript, the rule will not be properly applied). IE8 works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there will be an instance where this same come content is shown in a tooltip so I'll have to go with the jQuery option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both of your containers have the same `id`. Change it to `class`, since `id`'s purpose is a unique representation of an element.
2. I would do it like this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
       $(".listingItem").each(function()
       {
           isImgInside = $(this).find(".Image").length ? true : false;
           if(! isImgInside )
               $(this).find(".Text").width(450);
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: this is basically the same as my response

Answer (score 0):

or http://jsfiddle.net/C7fQ8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.listingItem:not(:has(.Image)) .Text').width(470);
});
```

width 470 to account for image div padding